# How to upload Node.js Application to FTP server?

Tags: node.js, ftp

I am kind of new to Node.js but I built an application and am pretty happy with it. I was wondering how would I go about uploading my Node.js application to an FTP server? Is it even possible to do this?

Comment: well... yeah... it's just a collection of files like any other.

Comment: @Keven, I tried using FileZilla and other methods of uploading it but no avail.

Comment: Not sure what to tell you. They're just files. Any FTP program should be able to upload them just like images or any other kind of files..

Comment: @KevinB, okay so you are saying I should just upload the Node.js Source code along with my application files? Do I have to make any references from my application files to find the node.js source files?

Comment: No, node.js has to be installed on the server separately, just like php or any other server-side language. you can't do that through ftp.

Comment: @KevinB, it is starting to make much more sense now thankyou. I think my problem is y web hosting provider doesn't support Node.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A Node.JS application is just a collection of files. You can upload them to another computer using FTP just like any other files.

That probably isn't what you are trying to ask though.

If you want to host a website built as a Node.JS application then you need to be using hosting that either:

- Explicitly supports Node.JS (Google finds [this list](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/node-hosting)) *or*
- Gives you full admin access (such as a virtual or dedicated server)

Such hosting will generally give you (at a minimum) shell access (via SSH) which you can use to run the Node.JS application.

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was looking for. Thank you.