# How to deploy a Node.js application to a remote server?

Tags: node.js, server, ftp

I have working node.js application on my computer working on port 3000 on localhost. Also I have ftp details of some remote server. I need to put this application there, but I don`t know how. Do you have any ideas/articles how it can be done?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upload Node.js Application to FTP server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31812412/how-to-upload-node-js-application-to-ftp-server)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to push application files only then you can push the application files on FTP server but if you want to host a node.js application then you need a server on which node.js can be installed and executed example: AWS EC2

[Here's the link](https://medium.com/@nishankjaintdk/setting-up-a-node-js-app-on-a-linux-ami-on-an-aws-ec2-instance-with-nginx-59cbc1bcc68c) for the doc to deploy node.js on EC2.

Answer (score 0):

If anybody is looking for a guideline to work remotely over ssh, using vscode to build and edit apps of the server.

Try this https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh-tutorial

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33054163)